# Is there a way to have Doctrine only hydrate a subset of associated entities in a collection through a DQL query condition?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Consider a one-to-many entity relationship between `Store` and `Location` entities (a `Store` has many `Location`s). Next consider a `Store` entity with 3 `Location`s:

```
Store (id = 1)
   locations
      (id = 1, opened = true)
      (id = 2, opened = true)
      (id = 3, opened = false)
```

Is there a way in DQL to fetch the Store by id but fetch it in such a way that the `locations` collection only contains `Location` entities that have the condition `opened = true`?

Currently I'm able to fetch the `Store` entity by id and then filter out the locations I don't want but I'm wondering if there is a way to never fetch the unwanted locations from the DB using a Doctrine DQL query and fetch the `Store` entity with a partially hydrated list of locations. Thanks.

Comment: Nop, you must make repository method that return filtered registries.

Comment: Or, filter with Criteria object your related collection.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to fetch all Stores that have an open Location. I didn't check if this has syntax errors:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT s FROM Store s JOIN s.location l WHERE l.open = '1');
$stores = $query->getResult();
```

Then you could invoke `getLocations()` for each store to get collection of the open `Location`-s. I assume you have the method `getLocations()` in your `Store` class.

You could also define relation as one-to-many bidirectional, and then you could run DQL query, something like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT l FROM Location l JOIN l.stores s WHERE s.id=[your specific Store ID] AND l.open='1');
```

That should yield the collection of `Location` objects.

More examples: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins